# How to add data from different rows and display them as columns of one row in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new in the SQL query field but I can do some queries. I would like to add related data in a table rows and display them in the same column. Here is the table containing the data:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Pivot. Do a group by, use case expressions.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: each student only have 3 point?

Comment: Yes, each student has only 3 points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are actually only 3 Questions and assuming the table was named Student you could do something like this:

```
select studentid AS Student,
(select Questionpoints from Student where studentid = a.studentid and Questionid = 8) AS Qn1,
(select Questionpoints from Student where studentid = a.studentid and Questionid = 9) AS Qn2,
(select Questionpoints from Student where studentid = a.studentid and Questionid = 10) AS Qn3
from Student as a
group by studentid;
```

Comment: note: I've slightly altered the column names, so don't just copy and past ;)

Comment: Thanks @Richard. This works for known Questionid, I would like to ask if possible to do this when Questionid is not known. The table above is only for one course, if I add questions for the next course, there will be new Questionids added to the table with respective students. Can I do this without specifying Questionid? Thanks

Comment: @Jef
if it is still only 3 Questions, just different ones you could probably replace the specific value with `select Questionpoints from Student order by Questionpoints LIMIT 1` for the first Question and `select Questionpoints from Student order by Questionpoints LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1` for the second question and so on. This is simple but probably not a very elegant solution and probably poor performance.

Comment: @Jef
remark: you might want to look at this: [link](http://buysql.com/mysql/14-how-to-automate-pivot-tables.html)
But I feel like that is not tooo trivial.

Comment: Thanks again @Richard, it worked with some modifications